# What is the different between Break and Return?

Tags: matlab, return, break

I have two Matlab codes that I want to determine a matrix is symmetric or not? I have used nested "for loops". Furthermore:

1. In the first code, I've got to exit of the program twice
   ''break''.
2. In the second code, I've got the command ''Return'' to
       exit of the program.

**Is there any problems between the Break and Return?**

I have attached my codes.

First code:

```
clc
clear all
A=input('Please enter your matrix=')
n=length(A);
temp=0;
for i=1:n-1
    for j=i+1:n
    if A(i,j)~=A(j,i)
       temp=1;
       break
    end
    end
    if temp==1
       disp('Matrix A is not symmetric.')
       break
    end
end
```

Second code:

```
clc
clear all
A=input('Please enter your matrix=')
n=length(A);
temp=0;
for i=1:n-1
    for j=i+1:n
    if A(i,j)~=A(j,i)
       disp('Matrix A is not symmetric.')
       return
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: See the documentation for [`break`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) and [`return`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html)...

Comment: If a method contains a loop,break end the loop ,return end the method.

Comment: Matrix symmetricity is checked via `max(max(A-A'))<tol`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are currently no issues in the code that you have posted. Here is a little bit of an elaboration on MATLAB's own documentation that will hopefully clear things up a bit for you.

According to the documentation, `break` will break out of a `for` or `while` loop:

> break terminates the execution of a for or while loop. Statements in the loop after the break statement do not execute.
>   In nested loops, break exits only from the loop in which it occurs. Control passes to the statement that follows the end of that loop.

For example the following will only break out of the innermost loop.

```
for k = 1:3

    fprintf('k = %d\n', k);

    for m = 1:4
        fprintf('m = %d\n', m);

        % Will go back and evaluate the loop using the next k
        break
    end
end
```

This will print

```
k = 1
m = 1
k = 2
m = 1
k = 3
m = 1
```

To break out of *both* loops you would need a second `break` in the outer loop as well.

```
for k = 1:3

    fprintf('k = %d\n', k);


    for m = 1:4

        fprintf('m = %d\n', m);

        % Will go back and evaluate the loop using the next k
        break
    end

    % Continue executing code after the for loop
    break
end 

disp('This will still execute')
```

This will print

```
k = 1
m = 1
This will still execute
```

On the other hand, `return` will break out of a *function*.

> return forces MATLAB® to return control to the invoking function before it reaches the end of the function. The invoking function is the function that calls the script or function containing the call to return. If you call the function or script that contains return directly, there is no invoking function and MATLAB returns control to the command prompt.

This means that `return` will completely exit out of a function (whether it is inside of a loop or not).

```
function looper()

    for k = 1:3
        fprintf('k = %d\n', k);

        for m = 1:4
            fprintf('m = %d\n', m);
            % No more iterations of ANY loop will be executed
            return
        end
    end

    disp('This will not execute')
end
```

This will print

```
k = 1
m = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**No**. There are no problems in using either. It depends completely on the purpose.

`break` terminates the execution of a `for` or `while` loop. Statements in the loop after the break statement do not execute.
In nested loops, break exits only from the loop in which it occurs. Control passes to the statement that follows the end of that loop. It retains the control in the outer block of the loop.

`return` forces MATLAB to return control to the invoking function before it reaches the end of the function. The invoking function is the function that calls the script or function containing the call to return. If you call the function or script that contains return directly, there is no invoking function and MATLAB returns control to the command prompt.

Within conditional blocks, such as `if` or `switch`, or within loop control statements, such as `for` or `while`, a `return` statement does not just exit the loop; it exits the script or function and returns control to the invoking function or command prompt.

In a nested loop control, `break` breaks out of the loop it is placed and continues the outer loop.